# Using a Django website on company intranet

Tags: python, django, intranet

I worked in an office for several months on the IT helpdesk and my boss asked me recently if I could possibly develop a small app for a few members of staff to use.

Having used Django with Python a few times I feel it would be a good idea to develop it this way, and figured a good idea would be to run the application on one of the company servers and just access it using an internal address. The servers are Windows Server 2003/2008.

How easy is it to achieve this? And other than Python what would have to be installed on the server which hosts the app/site?

Comment: Have you read about [django deployment](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite easy: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/

However, as your place is a Windows shop it might be worth evaluating ASP.net MVC especially if this is already in use.

Once you've done your research speak to whomever administers servers at your place of work and see if your plans fit within your company's existing standards.

Don't forget about backups and internal DNS.